# Retrieving the id from browser url?

Tags: php, url, get

Hello guys i have browser url like this

```
www.test.com/?category=3D&page=0
```

I want to make this url like

```
www.test.com/category/3D/0
```

in core php but when i make this like that so how to retrieve the `value 3D and o` from url.
help mi please !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Search for url rewriting, there are hundreds of questions already written addressing this topic.

Comment: You need to learn how to use `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache mod_rewrite to achive this. In your case the following .htaccess RewriteRule would do the job. For a better overview, see this [page](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/category/([A-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+) /index.php?category=$1&page=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set url rewriting using htaccess file, and then you can access your variables like $_GET['category'] even though url will be like www.test.com/category/3D/0